# Pandas Python convert list data in record to iterate row

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas in format like this

```
| Group    | ID_LIST        |
| -------- | -------------- |
| A        | [1,2,3]        |
| B        | [1,3,5]        |
| C        | [2,4]          |
```

I would like to delist into separate row like this

```
| Group    | ID_LIST        |
| -------- | -------------- |
| A        | 1              |
| A        | 2              |
| A        | 3              |
| B        | 1              |
| B        | 3              |
| B        | 5              |
| C        | 2              |
| C        | 4              |
```

If it possible to done with pandas function ? or should I approach with convert to list instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use explode

```
df = df.explode('ID_LIST')
```

Comment: Yeah This is what I looking for thank you

Answer (score 1):

If `ID_LIST` column contains real list:

```
>>> df.explode('ID_LIST')
   Group ID_LIST
0      A       1
0      A       2
0      A       3
1      B       1
1      B       3
1      B       5
2      C       2
2      C       4
```

If `ID_LIST` columns contains strings (which have the appearance of a list):

```
>>> df.assign(ID_LIST=pd.eval(df['ID_LIST'])).explode('ID_LIST')
   Group ID_LIST
0      A       1
0      A       2
0      A       3
1      B       1
1      B       3
1      B       5
2      C       2
2      C       4
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use Pandas explode() to separate list elements into separate rows() ?

```
df.assign(Book=df.Book.str.split(",")).explode('Book')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
pd.concat([Series(row['ID_LIST'], row['Group'].split(',')) for _, row in a.iterrows()]).reset_index()
```

Do let me know if it works